# Identify rows that replicate in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, replication

Please see below the dataset that I am working with:

```
  index d1_t1 d1_t2 d1_t3 d1_t4 d2_t1 d2_t2 d2_t3 d2_t4 d3_t1 d3_t2 d3_t3 d3_t4 d4_t1 d4_t2 d4_t3 d4_t4 d5_t1 d5_t2 d5_t3 d5_t4 d6_t1 d6_t2 d6_t3 d6_t4
   101     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
   200     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     0     0
   200     1     1     1     0     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
   101     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1

  d7_t1 d7_t2 d7_t3 d7_t4
    1     1     1     1
    1     1     0     0
    1     1     1     1
    1     1     1     1
```

A short explanation of the variables:

```
d1t1=Day 1 time 1
d1t2=Day 1 time 2
....
d2t1=Day2 time 1
d2t2=Day2 time 2
```

0,1= different types of measurements taken at a specific time

I would like to identify serials that have similar measurements across the week

Output:

```
  index d1_t1 d1_t2 d1_t3 d1_t4 d2_t1 d2_t2 d2_t3 d2_t4 d3_t1 d3_t2 d3_t3 d3_t4 d4_t1 d4_t2 d4_t3 d4_t4 d5_t1 d5_t2 d5_t3 d5_t4 d6_t1 d6_t2 d6_t3 d6_t4 d7_t1 d7_t2 d7_t3 d7_t4
1   101     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1     1
```

Sample data:

```
    df<-structure(list(index=c (101,200,200,101), d1_t1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
                   d1_t2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
                   d1_t3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
                   d1_t4 = c(1, 1, 0,  1),
                   d2_t1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
                   d2_t2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
                   d2_t3 = c(1, 0, 1 ,1), 
                   d2_t4 =c(1,0,1,1),
                   d3_t1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
                   d3_t2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
                   d3_t3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
                   d3_t4 = c(1, 0, 1,  1),
                   d4_t1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
                   d4_t2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
                   d4_t3 = c(1, 1, 1 ,1), 
                   d4_t4 =c(1,1,1,1),
                   d5_t1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1),
                   d5_t2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
                   d5_t3 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
                   d5_t4 = c(1, 1, 1,  1),
                   d6_t1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
                   d6_t2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
                   d6_t3 = c(1, 0, 1 ,1), 
                   d6_t4 =c(1,0,1,1),
                   d7_t1 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
                   d7_t2 = c(1, 1, 1, 1), 
                   d7_t3 = c(1, 0, 1 ,1), 
                   d7_t4 =c(1,0,1,1)), row.names = c(NA,4L), class = "data.frame")
                                                            
df
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One `dplyr` option could be:

```
df %>%
 group_by_all() %>%
 filter(n() > 1 & row_number() == 1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A `data.table` option:

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df)[, .I[.N > 1], by = names(df)]
```

That would leave you with a `V1` additional column though, you can of course remove it or do:

```
setDT(df)

df[df[, .I[.N > 1], by = names(df)]$V1, ]
```

If you want only a single row per series you can just wrap the last call into `unique`.